# LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL on exiting RCP application under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, swt, eclipse-rcp, ubuntu-11.10, ubuntu-unity

My RCP application's main menu appears in the global menu of Ubuntu 11.10, as expected. However, when exiting, I see these messages in the Eclipse console:

```
(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Application name:13458): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
```

It doesn't seem to actually have any impact so far, but is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above log messages look a lot like what I saw on my Ubuntu 12.04 with STS 3.0.0.M2 just yet.

I dug a bit into it and it seems this is a long standing bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563 that looks to be mostly fixed by now.

Comment #30 there references the LaunchPad issue that leads to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/865389 where you can find a workaround if you're really bothered about the log statements. This LP issue needs to be fixed before the Eclipse one can be considered fixed.